# Permanecer com input text preenchido após mudar de view asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu estou com a seguinte situação

Tenho uma view com um determinado campo, ao clicar em um botão ele chama uma determinada view, precisaria que ao clicar em um botão dessa outra view, ele chamasse essa view original com o form preenchido como estava.

Pensei que se ao salvar o que estava preenchido antes, e ao clicar no botão dessa outra view, iria aparecer o campo preenchido, só que está vindo vázio.

**script**

```
var descricao;
$('body').on('click', '#btnNovaAreaReclamacao', function () {
    descricao = $("#Descricao").val();
});

$('#btnSalvarNovaAreaReclamacao').on('click', function () {
    $("#Descricao").val(descricao);
    console.log(descricao);
});
```

**html da segunda view**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSalvarNovaAreaReclamacao" data-action="Create" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Cadastrar'>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                Nova
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Quando eu coloco por exemplo, funciona ao clicar no campo descrição mas não é o efeito que eu preciso

```
//nome do campo que eu estou usando
$('#Descricao').on('click', function () {
    $("#Descricao").val(descricao);
    console.log(descricao);
});
```

Também tentei

```
$('body').on('click', 'btnSalvarNovaAreaReclamacao', function () {
    $("#Descricao").val(descricao);
    console.log(descricao);
});
```

Como fazer para clicar no botão ele carregar esses dados corretamente?

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução:

```
$(window).load('btnSalvarNovaAreaReclamacao', function () {

});
```